# How can I access sprites in spritesheet by using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a script which is using a logo in 5 different sizes. The size of the logo is selected automatically after it calculate the ratio of my container. But now it is using this sizes as frames. Instead of using a folder with 5 images, I was wondering if there is any chance to grab the position of logo in a spritesheet.

Now I grab the logo size by using this:

```
var logotype = document.getElementById (name);
    console.log(logotype);
    if (logoTest){
        logotype.src = "logo/guides/logophase_0" + logoFrame + "guide.png";
    } else {
        logotype.src = "logo/logophase_0" + logoFrame + ".png";
    }
```

Instead of this I want to know if there is a way to use something like: `logotype.src = "logo/logophase.png";` and instead of `logoFrame = 1` or `2`, to be like `logoFrame = document.getElementById('frame1').style.backgroundPosition = ('0 -620px');`

Comment: No, you cannot use `<img src>` with sprites. What's wrong with 5 different images?

Comment: Is nothing wrong but I was wondering if there is a chance to use sprites instead multiple images.